# My question got deleted by a moderator; how can I find out the reason?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, moderators

[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28297266/eclipselink-jpa-hangs-on-bind) was deleted by a moderator after there had been an answer that was based on a misunderstanding. I had flagged the answer and asked that it be removed. 
Instead, now the whole question and answer are removed.

I'd like to understand the reason for the removal to decide how to proceed.
The question is still important for me—I'd still love to get a fix for the problem.

- How can I find out the reason for the removal?
- What would be good next steps to get an answer for the still open problem?

Comment: The answer was less appropriate/wrong after you changed the question. A better solution wuld be rolling back the question to when it did correspond to the answer and then asking another different question to get the somewhat different answer to the different question you're now asking, right?

Comment: That was a pretty good call, there is a new sheriff in town and he's cutting dead wood like he promised he would do.  Two years and two bounties were not enough to get it answered.  Then you finally get one, and you changed the question.  Who the heck ever gets stuck on a problem for two years??  Keeping this place tidy and useful is the responsibility of everyone, you too.

Comment: The question is about the behavior of these line:
https://github.com/BITPlan/com.bitplan.storage.sql/blob/master/src/main/java/com/bitplan/storage/sql/JPAEntityManager.java#L252 and https://github.com/BITPlan/com.bitplan.storage.sql/blob/master/src/main/java/com/bitplan/storage/sql/JPAEntityManager.java#L260 
In the original version there was a cut&paste / typing error. I am sorry that the problem never got fixed by JPA or anyone. I stil have to restart my software every once in a while when the issue happens. Hans Passant - are you suggesting I should stay put and not try to get a solution?

Comment: Think about the answerer is what you've done fair to them? They answered in good faith based on what you wrote at the time. Your cut&paste / typing error isn't their fault is it?

Comment: Add Robert Longson - formally the question looks like it has been changed. In fact it is still the same question. JPA hangs on a simple bind for a select * from entity e. The question has never been about some wrong java statement that never existed in the first place. The answer was following a mislead assumption. So I tried to fix the questions wording and what I got was a removal that I do not understand. Should I now simply ask the question again with a shorter example?

Comment: I'm confused.  If the question were closed, then it could make its way through the review queues and the community could decide to remove it.  The question itself wasn't exactly causing harm, but could be seen to be of no lasting value whatsoever.  I'm not exactly *thrilled* with the decision to outright delete it, but I don't find myself pining for a reversal, either.

Comment: I would love to hear an explanation though.

Comment: @WolfgangFahl Yes.  Linking to an external code repository and asking, essentially, for someone else to debug your code for you is a bit tall.  You need to reduce this to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It was deleted to prove that I voted for the right candidate in the moderator elections.

Comment: A new question has been out there for a while now see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45914761/eclipselink-hangs-on-bind

Answer (score 102, accepted):

I deleted the question because it looked completely abandoned to me. There were a bunch of noisy comments that no one had bothered to clean up after *many years* until I got an automatic flag about it. From a cursory glance at the comments, not to mention the elapsed time, it seemed like you did not yet have a clear, answerable question and were using the comments as a means to refine your question. That's a reasonable escape hatch, but it had been several years and nothing seemed to have come of it. Little to none of the discussion from the comments had been incorporated back into the question itself, and the question had received no real answers, so it looked like a dead question—something that was not adding any value to the community, and something that an automatic process routinely deletes anyway.

Worse than just not adding any value, though, it actually looked to me like the question was *doing harm* because it was attracting bad answers based on invalid information presented in the question. You yourself flagged the answer for that reason, and asked that it be deleted because it was "just a misunderstanding due to wrong citation".

I looked at the question, saw that you had corrected a typo in the most recent revision, and figured that after all the extended discussion in the comments, your problem had been solved some time ago—you'd simply failed to update the question to reflect it.

A question that is attracting confusion, extensive discussion in the comments, and bad answers is a prime candidate for deletion. So, for all of those reasons, instead of just deleting the answer you had flagged, I blew away the whole thing. The thinking was, essentially, why address the symptom when you can address the problem?

Aside from that, I kind of felt like it would be dirty pool to delete someone's honest attempt at an answer because you had an error in the question, no matter how simple the error seemed. They looked at the code in the question, saw it was wrong, and posted an answer that fixed it. The comment discussion on that answer was fast becoming hostile for precisely that reason—you telling them their answer was useless because it was based on a misunderstanding, and them not understanding why you should be able to change the code in the question out from underneath them. I didn't really understand that either.

That said, I'm open to the possibility that the question should *not* have been deleted. If you really have not yet solved the problem, and you can update the question so it is more clear to everyone (so it won't attract a bunch of noisy comments and unhelpful answers), then I would be happy to restore it.

Or you can start over and ask a new question, without any of the baggage of the past. Up to you.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation..  I'll restart the whole show and intend to first file a proper bug report with Eclipse JPA. I'd also love to see some kind of comment for deletions in the future. It that already a proposed feature that has been discussed or do I have to open a new change request for this on META?

Comment: There are no automatic comments upon deletion. I don't know if that's been proposed or not. We have to manually leave comments when we delete something. We usually do, but not always. In this case, it was kinda long to explain in a comment, and I honestly did not think this was going to be terribly controversial.

Comment: Well, that's quite a flawless answer.  Some day, possibly soon, you'll burn out on constantly having to justify yourself.  That will be a sad day.

Comment: Hooray for the new sheriff. (Warning: Frank Miller gets out of prison soon.)

Comment: @HansPassant Next time the answer will be written in a more generic way, and after that he can refer back to it in a comment. ;)

Comment: Hmya, that is not at all what my comment originally meant to convey.  It was edited by somebody with moderator rights, such changes are not traceable.  I was not complementary about the OP's motivation to ask this question and the harm that it does.  A taboo subject I suppose.

Comment: @Hans since when do "offensive" comments get edited with modified meaning rather than being deleted?

Comment: That is exactly what happened here, @Andras, and it does happen occasionally when a moderator deems the content as having *overall* value, but there is one little piece of it that is considered offensive or unnecessary. In this case, I dismissed two flags on Hans's comment, but when it got a third flag, I decided I'd better let someone else make the call. Their call was to edit out the last sentence.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Cody. I'm just somewhat put off by the fact that Hans' comment seemed to have changed meaning (or at least tone, but that matters to me too). Then again he could've deleted it afterwards if he were too unhappy with the end result.

Comment: There is now a bug report for JPA https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=521453 and I'll start a new question based on that.

Answer (score -2):

> - How can i find out the reason for the removal?

You can ask here on meta, kind of like you did. Though it's generally better to ask "Why was this question deleted?" rather than "How do I find out why this question was deleted?" - that is, just be direct. Just be sure you are honestly interested in learning so that you can make your future contributions to the site better. (I mean, if your goal in posting is merely to advertise to the community that the moderator made a supposedly wrong decision, that's not going to go over well.)

Perhaps a moderator will come along and post an answer here explaining in more detail why the question was deleted, or if the reason is obvious enough, a non-mod with enough reputation to view it might be able to explain for you.

> - What would be good next steps to get an answer for the still open problem?

That may depend on why the question was deleted, but in many cases, asking a followup question is a good approach. You might also try consulting people in an appropriate chat room if one exists.

Comment: I am generally interested in how I can find out the reasons for moderator actions. If there is no mechanims for it I'd love to see one in place. E.g. for downvotes it is good practice to add a comment. So I was hoping there would be some kind of comment for deletions also.